# parser with scopes and conditionals

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm writing a C/C++/... build system (I understand this is madness ;)), and I'm having trouble designing my parser.

My "recipes" look like this:

```
global
{
    SOURCE_DIRS src
    HEADER_DIRS include
    SOURCES bitwise.c \
            framing.c
    HEADERS \
            ogg/os_types.h \
            ogg/ogg.h
}
lib static ogg_static
{         
   NAME ogg
}
lib shared ogg_shared
{
    NAME ogg
}
```

(This being based on the super simple libogg source tree)

`#` are comments, `\` are "newline escapes", meaning the line continues on the next line (see QMake syntac). `{}` are scopes, like in C++, and global are settings that apply to every "target". This is all background, and not *that* relevant... I really don't know how to work with my scopes. I will need to be able to have multiple scopes, and also a form of conditional processing, in the lines of:

```
win32:DEFINES NO_CRT_SECURE_DEPRECATE
```

The parsing function will need to know on what level of scope it's at, and call itself whenever the scope is increased. There is also the problem with the location of the braces ( `global {` or `global{` or as in the example).

How could I go about this, using Standard C++ and STL? I understand this is a whole lot of work, and that's exactly why I need a good starting point. Thanks!

What I have already is the whole ifstream and internal string/stringstream storage, so I can read word per word.

Comment: This calls for the usual compiler/interpreter methods, and should probably be treated with the standard tools (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler and search for "parser generator" and similar).

Comment: the related links will surely help me form an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest (and this is more or less right out of the compiler textbooks) that you approach the problem in phases. This breaks things down so that the problem is much more manageable in each phase.

Focus first on the lexer phase. Your lexing phase should take the raw text and give you a sequence of tokens, such as words and special characters. The lexer phase can take care of line continuations, and handle whitespace or comments as appropriate. By handling whitespace, the lexer can simplify your parser's task: you can write the lexer so that `global{`, `global {`, and even

`global

{`

will all yield two tokens: one representing `global` and one representing `{`.

Also note that the lexer can tack line and column numbers onto the tokens for use later if you hit errors.

Once you've got a nice stream of tokens flowing, work on your parsing phase. The parser should take that sequence of tokens and build an abstract syntax tree, which models the syntactic structures of your document. At this point, you shouldn't be worrying about `ifstream` and `operator>>`, since the lexer should have done all that reading for you.

You've indicated an interest in calling the parsing function recursively once you see a scope. That's certainly one way to go. As you'll see, the design decision you'll have to repeatedly make is whether you literally want to call the same parse function recursively
(allowing for constructions like `global { global { ... } }` which you may want to disallow syntactically), or whether you want to define a slightly (or even significantly) different set of syntax rules that apply inside a scope.

Once you find yourself having to vary the rules: the key is to reuse, by refactoring into functions, as much stuff as you can reuse between the different variants of syntax. If you keep heading in this direction – using separate functions that represent the different chunks of syntax you want to deal with and having them call each other (possibly recursively) where needed – you'll ultimately end up with what we call a *recursive descent parser*. The Wikipedia entry has got a good simple example of one; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser .

If you find yourself really wanting to delve deeper into the theory and practice of lexers and parsers, I do recommend you get a good solid compiler textbook to help you out. The Stack Overflow topic mentioned in the comments above will get you started: [Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler)

Comment: This is what I was trying to get structured in my mind. Heck, the wikipedia article (why didn't I look there :s) will certainly help me get the basics. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[`boost::spirit`](http://boost-spirit.com/) is a good recursive descent parser generator that uses C++ templates as a language extension to describe parser and lexer.  It works well for native C++ compilers, but won't compile under Managed C++.

Codeproject has a [tutorial article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/introduction_spirit.aspx) that may help.

Answer (score 1):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (use [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works)), after that you can look for [FLEX](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/)/[BISON](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) and others like [lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/). There are many tools out there but ANTLR and flex/bison should be enough. I personally like ANTLRWorks too much to recommend something else.

**LATER**: With ANTLR you can generate parser/lexer code for a [variety of languages](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the point of the project is specifically learning how to write a lexer and shift-reduce parser, I'd recommending using Flex and Bison, which will handle much of the parsing grunt-work for you. Writing the grammar and semantic analysis will still be a whole lot of work, don't worry ;)

Comment: Well, I see this as a "Learn C++ the hard way" academic self-tutor trial-and-error thing, if you get what I'm saying :). I think it's a worthwhile cause, and will certainly show me enough of the Standard Library and STL to get a good grip on C++ IMHO. Heck, I'll even learn about compilers and linkers in the process.

Comment: @rubenvb: then write a recursive decent parser. The simplest exaplin-by-doing reference I know for that is the Crenshaw Tutorial (linked in 1669).

Comment: @dmckee Is recursive descent reasonable for grammar of the complexity the OP suggests in his post? I'd think that that way madness lies...

Comment: @user: Recursive decent would be fine for this. Crenshaw's tutorial builds a recursive decent parser for a pascal-like language which has considerable more complexity.