# C++ Interpreter/Shell

Tags: c++, string, shell, interpreter

I'm asking this question mostly because I'm curious.

Mostly for fun, I'm trying to develop a basic interpreter & shell in C++. Now, I already developed a basic shell - I can `CD`, `dir`, and whatnot, and I'm asking this mostly in order to learn. :)

As a part of the interpreter, I want to save *user-declared variables*. I.e: `param x = 'siosidf';` or `param x = 5;`.

I also would like to be able to preform *pure calculations*, i.e `72*32` or `23 + 82 * 2` should output `2304` or `187`, recpectivley.

Note that I also want to be able to apply *operators on variables*, like so:

`param x = 72;`

`x = x + 23;`

`print x;`

Needs to output `95`.

My question has two parts:

*First*, how would you (doesn't have to be actual code, but if you do it, please do it in C++ :) ) implement the variable saving system? (Please also explain why, since I'm doing it in order to learn. :) )

*Second*, how would you tell apart different calculations/declarations/calls and preform them in all their different forms effectively? (Spaces, such as `72*83` vs. `72 * 83`.)

Comment: You might want to find a good book or course on writing interpreters.

Comment: This is a neat project, but this question is not a StackOverflow FAQ-type question :(

Comment: @MooingDuck why so? It really is about programming & concepts, I think... If it doesn't fit in here, where should i ask it?

Comment: Regarding the first question, if only there was some to *map* something like a string to a value... ;)

Comment: Probably belongs on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Might like to look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/picoc/)

Comment: @A.Abramov _"why so?"_ Because it's much too broad for possible solutions. You can use e.g. a `std::map<std::string,int>` to keep variable values stored, but a lot of better, more generic solutions will be available.

Comment: @glennjackman - This looks like more of an implementation issue and would be better answered here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @dwn I`m trying to take a look at the source, but for some reason it throws me a 404. Do you have any idea where could i take a look at it? Thank you :)

Comment: @A.Abramov: What you're looking for is a parser. (The people suggesting map are not fully grasping the problem I think).  The simplest to understand is a [Recursive Decent Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

Comment: @A.Abramov https://picoc.googlecode.com/files/picoc-2.1.tar.bz2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a map.
2. Use a parser. Boost.Spirit would be a good choice.

Comment: I was writing a lengthy answer, but this sums it up.  Boost spirit is easy to use and will do the job, but to be old-school you should consider flex and bison as well.  Anyway, this answer from @StenSoft is correct.

Comment: Both sound like good ideas; However, this project is not for a product; i'd like to implement the parser myself. I'll mark this as the answer in a hour if nobody else answers. Thank you :)

Comment: @A.Abramov if you really want to implement the parser yourself you need this: [The dragon book](http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-Edition/dp/0321486811) It's the bible of compilers. But be warned: it very advanced. Not suited for beginners or intermediates. Although you need just some of the chapters in it. Mainly those around LL and/or LR Parsers.

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself, consider checking [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3085141/4538344).