# C++ FSM design and ownership

Tags: c++, parsing, oop, fsm

I would like to implement a FSM/"pushdown automaton" parser for this syntax: [parser with scopes and conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025293/c-general-parser-with-scopes-and-conditionals) which has already been "lexed" into [Finite State Machine parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085070/finite-state-machine-parser)

I have the following:

```
class State
{
public:
    virtual State* event( const string &token );
    State* deleteDaughter();
private:
    A* m_parent;
    A* m_daughter;
}
class SomeState : public State
{
public:
    State* event( const std::string &token );
}
```

With `B`'s `event()` doing (after many if-elseif's) `return m_parent->deleteDaughter()`. I know this is fishy (and it crashes), but I need  way to return the parent `State` from the daughter `State` and make sure the daughter `State` isn't leaked.

My event loop looks like this:

```
while( somestringstream >> token )
    state = state->event();
```

Before you scold the design and last piece of code, I tried extending a much too simple example from [here](http://www.objectvalue.com/articles/CppFiniteStateMachine.html), which seems pretty ok. I am moving the decision part to the states themselves, for clarity and brevity.

I understand there's loads of books on this subject, but I'm no computer scientist/programmer and I want to learn to do this myself (of course, with the help of all the friendly people at SO). If the concept isn't clear, please ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to still post your take on this, but I have figured out how to handle everything gracefully:

First: my event loop will keep a pointer to the last `State*` created.

Second: Each `State` has a pointer to the parent `State`, initialized in the constructor, defaulting to 0 (memory leak if used for anything but the first `State*`); this guarantees that no State will go out of scope.

Third: `State* endOfState()` function which does exactly this (and I'm particularly proud of this.

```
State* State::endOfState()
{
    State* parent = m_parent; // keep member pointer after suicide
    delete this;
    return parent;
}
```

When this is called from within a subclass's `event()`, it will properly delete itself, and return the parent pointer (going one up in the ladder).

If this still contains a leak, please inform me. If the solution is not clear, please ask :)

PS: for all fairness, inspiration was stolen from http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=179284